# Is there a way to select a range of cells at the end of each column on a cross table to perform a calculation

Tags: business-objects, webi

I need to select a range of the last 3 to 5 cells w/in each column and calculate an average to which the result needs to be output beneath the selected cells.

[image: webi results]

[image: Desired output modeled in Excel]

Comment: can you give a detailled example of what you want to achieve ? I dont really get it :)

Comment: Could you export what you have in your screenshot to Excel and then add the averages where you are expecting them and show us that? Also, I don't know how to average values like **0.64 - 21 - 21**. Please explain.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I kicked it out to Excel to build what I'm looking for. Attached is a screencap, please let me know if I need to explain that more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may try to add a rank dimension that you add in  your table (then you hide) and you compute your avg(columnName where rank > value) 
2 ways to do it 
- the rank should be in desc order then in the avg --> rank<=5 
- the rank is in esc order --> You will need to use count() to get the number of line - 5